# How to add file attachments to appointment using EWS?

Tags: c#, outlook, exchangewebservices, appointment

I'm developing application which uses EWS managed API to send appointments to outlook recipients,
Now there are requirement to add attachments to appointment, I'm  able  to attach attachments to emails, but when I use same technique as attaching item attachments to email ,but attachments are not attaching, my code as below

```
       public string sendCalanderEvntAsReply( EntityLayer.Data_Contracts.AppointmentDTO appointment)
       {

               Appointment app = new Appointment(service);
               app.Subject = appointment.Subject;
               app.Body = appointment.Body;
               app.Start = Convert.ToDateTime(appointment.Start);
               app.End = Convert.ToDateTime(appointment.End);
               app.Location = appointment.Location;

               foreach (string obj in appointment.Attendees)
               {
                   app.RequiredAttendees.Add(obj);
               }

               if (appointment.Attachments != null &&
                   appointment.Attachments.Count > 0)
               {
                   foreach (var att in appointment.Attachments)
                   {
                       app.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(att.FileName);
                   }
               }

               app.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);       
}
```

is there any issue in my code?
please help.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With EWS when you want to send an Attachment with the Meeting invitation you need to save the appointment first before you send the message else you will only get the attachment on the owners copy so with your code you should use something like

```
           Appointment app = new Appointment(service);
           app.Subject = appointment.Subject;
           app.Body = appointment.Body;
           app.Start = Convert.ToDateTime(appointment.Start);
           app.End = Convert.ToDateTime(appointment.End);
           app.Location = appointment.Location;



           if (appointment.Attachments != null &&
               appointment.Attachments.Count > 0)
           {
               foreach (var att in appointment.Attachments)
               {
                   app.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(att.FileName);
               }
           }
           app.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);

           foreach (string obj in appointment.Attendees)
           {
               app.RequiredAttendees.Add(obj);
           }

          app.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);
```

Comment: I am having a similar issue when removing attachments and adding new ones. But this solution did not work for me. Here is my case if probably u could have a glimpse:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48658409/how-to-update-delete-file-attachments-to-appointment-using-ews